# Show tables with LIKE and NOT REGEXP

Tags: mysql

I would like to get all tables in a database which start with "`wp_`" but not with "`wp_X`" (where X is a digit)

```
SHOW TABLES FROM database 
 WHERE Tables_in_database 
 LIKE 'wp_%' AND Tables_in_database
 NOT REGEXP 'wp_[0-9]+%'
```

gives me all including `wp_2*`, `wp_3*`,...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SHOW TABLES FROM database 
 WHERE Tables_in_database 
 LIKE 'wp_%' AND Tables_in_database
 NOT REGEXP 'wp_[0-9]+'
```

ie, remove the `%` character from regex.

Comment: aaah, that was from the previous `LIKE`! Thanks!

Comment: Be careful, as `_` is a special character itself.