# Laravel Dynamic Database Table Names

Tags: database, laravel, dynamic, migration

Is there a way to create database tables dynamically in Laravel. I have one Laravel build which has a database schema for quotes using the migrations tool. There will be several customers using the system which need to each have their own database table.

What I would like to happen is that when a function is called by the customer it will use the quotes schema to create a new table like 'customer1_quotes' and use this table for the customer in future. Additionally when migrations are run it will apply the updates to all tables with the given name structure (*_quotes).

If anyone has details to achieve this or a recommend alternative approach please message :)

Comment: table name: `quotes`.
store datas in `customer_id`, `quote` column.

Comment: This is the approach that was first entertained, but caused too many complications with day to day data management and data migrations.

Answer (score 0):

### Create a trait used by observers

Create a trait which loops through your customers and creates/updates the tables. You don't have to be in a migration to call `DB::`.
Use the trait in `create`/`update` controllers or better for model `create`/`update` observers. You could also create a console command for manual triggering or testing.

This should not be executed during maintenance. Using `php artisan down` should ensure no jobs are run during migrations.

The migrations for the `customer{id}_quotes` tables can loop through the available tables by querying table names using `LIKE` and/or `REGEXP`. See link below.

### Links

- [Laravel Model Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#observers)
- [How to dynamically set table name in Eloquent Model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47987005/10441671)
- [Laravel's table `Blueprint` docs (5.8)](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html)
- [Get table names using `LIKE` or `REGEXP`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30997081/show-tables-with-like-and-not-regexp)
- [Optimization: Chunking results when getting query builder results](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#chunking-results)

*Edit:* A repeatable migration probably won't work well and is confusing to others. Using a trait for flexibility to use for an observer is better for this.